# How can people with debilitating social phobias get through foreign language?

Tags: teaching, learning, disability, psychology

I almost didn't get my BS degree because I have never successfully tolerated a foreign language course. My most recent attempt was no exception. I paced about in front of the building trying unsuccessfully to force myself to enter the classroom. Surely this represents a severe defect of my character, but I maintain that an alternate teaching strategy would make success possible for someone like me. An extreme social phobia of this type is rare (<2%). There will never be a house reform because those who gravitate to teaching language are extroverted, and communication is a social activity. so there is little basis for empathy. This is something that I need to figure out, because I learned that the math PhD program requires fourth-semester proficiency. I am sure that the masses love this ubiquitous type of social teaching philosophy, and that the best way to handle statistical anomalies is to tell them to "get over themselves" and "get with the program". This is what I have tried to do, so much against my nature. Language is the only department where this is a problem for me. The format is always the same.

How can someone with a debilitating social phobia get through a foreign language course?

Comment: It's unclear how a social phobia relates only to the language learning portion of your degree. Language class aren't that different from tutorial type coursework.

Comment: Language courses are (always) about 10% lecture and 90% group work. I do not know what a TA session is, but if the coursework had a standard lecture format I would probably do well. I am seeking strategies that may be employed by a 100% briggs-myers introvert to successfully navigate through a 4'th semester language requirement.

Comment: The problem could be solved by taking a written-only language, such as Latin, Ancient Greek or Sanskrit, which tend to follow more traditional un-social pedagogy.

Comment: @reluctantmathematician Where are you getting these numbers? I don't know what country you're talking about, but at least in all of the languages courses I've taken (one of my majors is French and I'm taking Japanese and Russian electively), about 75% of the course is lecture and 25% group work. I live in the United States, attending an average university. I work in our language department, and the vast majority of courses are like this. Moreover, it was even *more* time spent in lecture when I was studying abroad  in France.

Comment: @reluctantmathematician And to counter "*those who gravitate to teaching language are so extroverted that there is not even a basis for empathy*", I am an introvert (even according to the B-M test), and I plan to teach English and French in the future. Don't think that I'm not being empathetic - I'm good friends with a girl who recently dropped out of all her French courses due to social anxiety; I understand why this is an issue. I just don't see validity in your claims about foreign language learning and teaching...

Comment: My scornful tones are admittedly unnecessary; I was not attempting to disqualify the entire profession, although I do not think that schools should force the unwilling into a language. In my experience the cited numbers are fairly accurate, but I am willing to concede this point which does not diminish my conundrum. The point is that language makes me uncomfortable in a way that is unprecedented in other departments and if any empathy exists it has had no effect on the outcome. This almost ruined my academic career. What can be said for your friend who dropped out due to anxiety?

Comment: I just read this question and was definitely colored with intrigue. Would you mind me asking you a few questions? In your dreams do you speak out more freely? Is your phobia of a specific foreign language or is it all of them? Can you point me to more resources about this phobia specifically? It's the first time I read of it.

Comment: @JerrySaravia: The OP has social phobia (social anxiety disorder), not a specific phobia of a foreign language. His/her issue is with language instruction, which generally involves a high level of direct social interaction, rather than with the subject matter itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about how to learn foreign languages, not a question about academia.

Comment: @reluctantmathematician My friend has social anxiety and is an anxious person in general. In one of her French courses they were tasked with role-playing famous French artists in order to sell their art to (fake) buyers (French students in other courses). It was a semester-long project and I suppose that the stress of needing to role-play in French turned her off to the language. She says that she's going to continue later, but she couldn't handle it this semester. Two of the courses she was taking were taught by a professor who emphasizes in-class engagement more than every other French prof.

Comment: The only way I got through the undergraduate requirement was to take the proficiency exam multiple times. I treated this exam like a cryptography puzzle, returning one meaningless symbol for another according to an algorithm. There is not any validity to this metric, but it was enough to get a degree awarded. At the new institution the evaluation requires translation of passages from foreign textbooks into English. I have 2 years to obtain proficiency; I will try do this without taking any language coursework.

Comment: Maybe it's been so long now that the question is moot, but I wanted to ask - what was really the deal with the foreign language requirement?  Math PhD programs do often have a language requirement, but I've never heard of one that would require anywhere near four semesters of language study. Typically they only require proficiency at reading, which is only about a quarter of most language courses (reading / writing / speaking / listening), and surely the least problematic part for you.

Comment: Moreover, it's proficiency at reading *mathematics* in the foreign language, which is much easier than reading general texts or literature - many of the technical terms are cognates, and mathematical writing tends to follow a quite restricted pattern.  I successfully passed a math PhD language exam in French without ever taking a French class in my life.  (I had taken some classes in Spanish which helped a little, but I think I could have done it without them.)

Comment: I have voted to reopen because the question is not really about learning a foreign language in general, but rather about satisfying a foreign language proficiency requirement for a graduate program in another field.    (And I would suggest editing to focus on that aspect.) This particular kind of requirement is unique to academia and may involve different approaches than just trying to learn the language.  I think Academia.SE is a better community for this question than a language-learning or linguistics forum could be.

Comment: This matter is resolved. My current program allows a diagnostic tool such as Matlab or R to be considered a foreign language. They also permit translation of textbooks using a dictionary and allow 48 hours to complete the assignment. At the time of this inquiry there was concern because two of the schools I applied required an equivalent of second year proficiency. An edit was recently completed because I could not delete the question, which contains too many adverbs and excessive victimology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... I paced about in front of the building trying unsuccessfully to force myself to enter the classroom. ...

I'll be honest with you. If you cannot get over yourself and force yourself to face your fears, there's little point in getting your degree, since you're extremely unlikely to land a job that requires a degree in which you could function.

If you don't want to quit, my advice is to deliberately seek out social occasions as often as possible. Face your fears and try to desensitise yourself to your phobia. It will be hard, but it's the only way.

Comment: -1. Facing one's fears, especially alone, is *not* the only way to combat a phobia. OP might benefit from a professional therapist.

Answer (score 29):

First, social phobia is not a character defect. It is a recognized medical condition. You are not worth less as a human being if you suffer from a phobia.

Next, depending on your school, you may be able to get a medical exemption from certain requirements. You may want to discuss this with your local student services. (By email if meeting people in person is impossible to you.)

However, *I would strongly advise against this approach*. You will need to interact with people after leaving college, too, so avoiding the problem is not a good strategy in the long run. Instead, I would recommend that you actively work on this issue.

The good news is that social phobia is very amenable to cognitive behavioral therapy (CBT). The accepted form of therapy is a desensitization approach, where you will progressively learn to tolerate being around people.

No, this will not be easy. You will need to work on your disability. You will encounter setbacks. But your student services should again be able to point you towards resources and therapists that can help you. And there is no better time for doing this therapy than now, when you have a more-or-less flexible schedule, and before you hit the job market, where social phobia will be an *enormous* problem - regardless of which career you want to pursue.

Good luck!

Comment: Since it is a disability, I would think that (at least in the US) the school should accept reading/writing proficiency as an alternative, so online courses &c would suffice.

Comment: @Kimball It'd read like that if it was unprompted or out of the blue, but I think it was in reaction to this comment in the question: "Surely this represents a severe defect of my character..." so there is context to it.

Comment: @user568458 Ah, thanks, I missed that line in the OP (or had forgotten it) when reading this answer.

Answer (score 12):

I am not aware of your location, but I can comment on the position in the UK. If a student (or academic or researcher) declares a disability to their institution then (together with clinicians or other appropriate evidence and an assessment of need) they are required by law (Disability Discrimination in Education) to make provision and adjustments (except for where the adjustment would be unreasonable). Only the courts can rule what is reasonable or not.

However, an individual may choose to keep their condition private, in which case the institution has no obligations until the point of disclosure. Privacy law overrides disability law in such cases.

I have responsibilities for students with alternate needs in my subject area, and this includes students with social phobia conditions. Some as extreme as you describe.

We have, for example, conducted oral examinations and tutorial using skype between two adjacent rooms so that the student does not have to share a space or be overlooked by another person.

It can be done, if there is a will and a motivation to do it on behalf of the institution.

**Edit:** however I also strongly concur with Stephan's answer. When a student has declared they are offered help and support. In particular CBT and other therapies are very helpful in putting students and staff in better positions for employment and promotion.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to take an online course. There are many MOOCs that offer foreign language courses. You may then try and solve assignments and take exam of the real course to get the credit. Of course this will require some convincing to the authorities that you would like to skip attending because of the phobia. I should add that you may want to consider seeking therapy for your condition. I have heard positive stories of therapies working, even the rare cases as you describe.

Comment: Many unis won't happily tranfer credit from a MOOC.
But on a very similar note, many unis offer corses via corespondance, which has similar advantage.